# Hello ffmpeg heroes - please help me with ffmpeg/ffprobe commands to decode a video for me?

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, ffprobe

I have a sample.mp4 which is currently not playable on VLC or media player and I've checked the FFmpeg values and get the below result? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: It would help if you would post your ffmpeg command. Preferably as text.

Comment: Apologies. it was just ffmpeg -i sample.mp4

Answer (score 1):

It is all about the proprietary codec, i.e. IMM5. The VLC and FFMPEG can't deal with it except patching the avcodec manually using https://patchwork.ffmpeg.org/project/ffmpeg/patch/20190716170703.10960-1-onemda@gmail.com/. Of course, you need to re-compile the ffmpeg using the IMM5 supported avcodec lib.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try my luck.